# Optimizing a component tree

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm currently in the process of finding improvements I could make to my app, and I was curios about the following scenario.

Say I have a `<Header />` stateless functional component that has the sole job of rendering two container components which are connected to a redux store.

I was thinking about promoting the `<Header />` component to a container, connecting it to redux and passing down props to the subcomponents.

Would that make more sense both in terms of performance and common sense ? Having just one component connected to the store, instead of the two subcomponents.

Comment: From the Redux FAQ: https://redux.js.org/faq/react-redux#should-i-only-connect-my-top-component-or-can-i-connect-multiple-components-in-my-tree

Answer (score 0):

That is actually a perfectly valid way of doing that. The (react-)redux documentation even says that using connect() should't be used on every single component. It is definetly okay to pass down props one or two components!